# Using the same value for two attributes in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm setting up an `Artist` model that has `name`and `birth_name` attributes. In some cases, an artist's stage name is synonomous with their real name, vice-versa. What I'd like to do in my factory is use the `birth_name` (created using Faker) as the `name` attribute.  I tried simply referencing as so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :artist do
    name { birth_name }
    birth_name { Faker::Name.name }
  end
end
```

but get this error:

```
ArgumentError: Factory not registered: birth_name
```

What's the best way to get this to work?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :artist do
    birth_name { Faker::Name.name }
    name { birth_name }
  end
end
```

Reference:
[FactoryBot - Dependent Attributes](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#dependent-attributes)

Comment: That will throw error too. Because that's for actual attributes, not virtual.

Comment: Actually this does work for newer versions of FactoryGirl

Comment: This works in factory_bot 4.11.0. one interesting thing is if you have mistakenly provide the same attribute name both inside and outside, entire thing will crash with a segfault:  name { name }